# CloudFront Returns 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured a CloudFront distribution to point to an application load balancer (ALB). The ALB points to a lambda function. I have configured an A record in Route53 to point to the CloudFront distribution.

Hitting the ALB directly via its generated domain name, works (ie. the lambda is hit and runs and returns OK).

Attempting to hit the application via the domain and CloudFront returns a 502 error:

```
502 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

How can I best troubleshoot this? Are there any frequent pitfalls I might have fallen in to?

Comment: I would start by checking that you can access your ALB from the internet (without using a VPN). Then double check your CF Origin settings to make sure it correctly matches the ALB. I might also create a DNS A record (Route53) that points to the ALB. Verify that works from the internet, then use that record in the Origin. Also check Security Group rules on the ALB.